# Printing pointers returned by a function inside loop

Tags: c++, pointers

I am making a c++ program which will replace all the spaces from a char array with "%20".
For ex, "This is some text with some spaces" will be converted to "This%20is%20some%20text%20with%20some%20spaces"

PLEASE SEE IN PROGRAM COMMENTS WHICH LINE IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY.

replacer function in this program takes pointer to char array and size of the string.
Then method creates new char array with replaced spaces and function returns pointer to replaced char array.

The problem in this program is with printing char array in main function whose pointer is returned by the replacer.

"replaced" is the pointer variable which is pointing to replaced string. In main function I am trying to print char array using "replaced" pointer.

If I print everything manually it works fine.
Eg, if i do :  `cout << *replaced << *(replaced+1) << *(replaced+2)` ....
The whole string will be printed.

But inside loop it gives me garbage value. Please let me know where in the code I am making any mistake. Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of execution of program]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char * replacer(char * text, unsigned int size )
{
    int space_count = 0, i = 0, new_size = 0;
    cout << "Given text : ";
    for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        cout << *(text + i) ;
        char temp = *(text + i);
        if (temp == ' ')
        {
            space_count++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number of spaces in given text : " << space_count << endl;
    new_size = size + ( 2 * space_count );

    char replaced_string[new_size];
    int counter = 0 ;
    for(i = 0 ;i < size; i++)
    {
        char temp = *(text + i);
        if(temp == ' ')
        {
            replaced_string[counter++] = '%';
            replaced_string[counter++] = '2';
            replaced_string[counter++] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            replaced_string[counter++] = temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "in replacer method : " << replaced_string << endl;
    char * pointer_to_replaced;
    pointer_to_replaced = replaced_string;
    return pointer_to_replaced;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    char original[] = "This is some text with some spaces";
    char * original_pointer = original;
    char *replaced;
    replaced = replacer(original_pointer, sizeof(original));
    //cout << *(replaced) << *(replaced+1) << *(replaced+2) << *(replaced+3) << *(replaced+4) << endl;
    // ABOVE LINE WORKS FINE
    for(t=0;t<20;t++)
    {
        cout<<*(replaced+t);  // THIS IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY
    }
    cout <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is almost already done for you with `std::string::replace`.

Comment: Since you are calling this a C++ program, I recommend getting rid of the C components, such as character arrays.  Use `std::string`.  This is where your bugs are coming from.

Comment: `replaced_string` is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are allocating `replaced_string` on the stack, and then expecting it to retain its value after returning from the function. You should allocate on the heap instead, and remember to `delete[]` the memory afterwards. The stack goes away when a function returns.

```
//    char replaced_string[new_size];
    char* replaced_string = new char[new_size];
```

A second problem is that you need to null-terminate your `replaced_string` after the loop.

```
replaced_string[counter] = '\0';
```

Additionally, you do not need to loop through to print out the return value. You can use `cout` directly.

```
cout << replaced << endl;
```

There may be other latent issues as well, but fixing those three will make the code functional.

Comment: Thank you. But then how manually printing all characters work ?

cout << *replaced << *(replaced+1) << *(replaced+2) ...

Comment: Yes, Storing on the heap solves the problem. But still it would be great if you give specific explanation why manually printing pointers is working

Comment: @Hardik, When you try to access stack variables from a stack frame that is already expired, you have undefined behavior. For your specific question, it is probably because the `cout` function call to do the first print corrupts the data on the stack so that the loop prints garbage.